# How to install multiple apps simultaneously with single set of permission in Android?

Tags: java, android, apk, android-permissions, android-install-apk

Basically what I want to do is, I have an app which works like a store platform like Google play store. So that you can install any app through my app into your device. Say, I have set of 5 apps in the store as a bundle where all the apps has same set of permissions required from the user. Is there a way where I can download all the 5 apps simultaneously without prompting the user 5 times regarding the permission before installation?

I am not sure whether it violates any Android policy. On the other hand I know that if you try to access any resource without the appropriate permission, it will throw run time exception. Is there a way to overcome this? And I don't want to root the phone on any case.

Comment: doing this would require root, but yes it is possible, that's how many backup apps work.

Comment: Thanks @Eluvatar. Can you point me a reference on it or can you give me a hint on how to do it? Backup/restore apps works fine because the permissions are there already I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way where I can download all the 5 apps simultaneously without prompting the user 5 times regarding the permission before installation?

Not without root.

> Is there a way to overcome this?

No.

> I am not sure whether it violates any Android policy

If you were planning on distributing this app through the Play Store, please hire an attorney and have that attorney review [the developer distribution agreement](http://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html), particularly paragraph 4.5.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not aimed for play store. I am just figuring it out whether there is a way to install all my apps in a single batch without disturbing user on each install.

Comment: Note that the google play app is not "root" - 3rd part add-on attempts may utilize that as an end-run around the android security framework, but the design intent is that this be done by a system app, which *does not* involve the superuser (root) account, but rather closely held permissions.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Sorry, in this case I meant root as a means of getting installed on the system partition.